# Why is Chi-squared not proportional to errors.

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

One can find Chi-squared by using

$\chi^2=\sum \frac{\left(value \ expected_i-value \ measured_i\right)^2}{\sigma_i^2}$

And the quality of the fit is evaluated by how small Chi-squared is. But how should I interpret the error $\sigma$ being in the denominator. Shouldn't large errors inflate the Chi-squared value rather than minimize it? Shouldn't we get large Chi-squared when errors are large? Because data cannot be fitted closely and therefore Chi-squared cannot then be expected to be able to attain a small value.

Comment: Your use of "errors" is unclear.  The numerator measures "errors" in the measured data compared to their expected values.  The denominator measures expected size of "errors".  At each of your uses of "errors", it is unclear whether you are referencing the numerator or the denominator.

Comment: Always referring to the denominator.

Comment: Then you should consider why we would expect the numerator and the denominator to grow together or shrink together, in such a way that the scale factors cancel.

Answer (score 1):

What you call $\chi^2$ is a weighted least squares, ie a distance between model and data.  Having $\sigma_i$ on the denominator reduces the weight of samples that have large fluctuations.

Regarding goodness of fit, if the fluctuations are gaussian, then that quantity $\Delta^2 = \sum_i \frac{(expected_i - measured_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}$ should follow a $\chi^2_d$ statistical distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom equal to the the number of samples minus the number of fit parameters.  The expectation of $\chi^2_d$ is $d$.  Given the distribution of $\chi^2_d$, values much larger than $d$ are unlikely. Goodness of fit can be quantified by $p$, the probability $\chi^2_d$ gives a value at least as large as the value of $\Delta^2$ observed.  Small values of $p$ indicate tension between the data and the model.  Remember that $p$ depends on the number of degrees of freedom, not just on the ratio $\Delta^2/d$: for $d=3$, $\Delta^2/d \geq 4/3$ is not uncommon, but for $d=3000$ it is very rare.

Be aware that in practice, values of $\Delta^2$ much smaller than $d$ can also mean that the $\sigma_i$ have been overestimated.